# The Fourier Transform of the Derivative

Tags: real-analysis, limits, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, supremum-and-infimum

Obs.: I'm studying Fourier analysis but this is more a real-analysis/limits/suprema-infima question.

> Let $\mathcal S$ be the Schwartz space on $\mathbb R$, i.e., the set of functions $f\in\cal C^{\infty}$ on $\mathbb R$ such that for every $k,l\ge 0$
> $$
> \sup |x|^k|f^{(l)}(x)|<\infty.
> $$
> The Fourier transform of a function $f\in\mathcal S$ is defined by
> $$
> \hat f(\xi) := \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{-2\pi ix\xi}\space dx.
> $$

Proposition: The Fourier transform of $f'$ is the function $\xi\mapsto 2\pi i\xi\hat f(\xi)$.

The proof I'm reading goes by the following:

$$
\int_{-N}^Nf'(x)e^{-2\pi ix\xi}dx = \left[f(x)e^{-2\pi ix\xi}\right]_{-N}^N - \int_{-N}^Nf(x)e^{-2\pi ix\xi}(-2\pi i\xi) dx = f(N)e^{-2\pi iN\xi}-f(-N)e^{-2\pi i(-N)\xi} + 2\pi i\xi\int_{-N}^Nf(x)e^{-2\pi ix\xi}dx
$$

Then by making $N\to\infty$ we get the result.

Here I just don't know why $f(N)e^{-2\pi iN\xi}-f(-N)e^{-2\pi i(-N)\xi}$ goes to $0$. I only know how to use that $f\in\cal S$ to get that this expression is bounded, but I don't see how it guarantees that it goes to zero.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $|f(N)e^{-2\pi iN\xi}-f(-N)e^{-2\pi i(-N)\xi}|\le|f(N)|+|f(-N)|.$ Use that $f\in\mathcal S$ to get that this upper bound goes to $0.$

Comment: Note that $\sup|xf(x)|$ is bounded.